# C struct used in a C++ code generates an error "call to implicitly-deleted..."

Tags: c++, c

Mixing C and C++.

My header file: (got it from external source)

```
typedef struct
    {
    int ia;
    float fa;
} Struct_A;

typedef struct
{
    Struct_A sA;
    int ib;
    float fb;
    const int Array[16]; // This is causing the ISSUE.
} Struct_B;

typedef struct {
Struct_B sB;
int k;
...
}Struct_C;
```

My cpp file: (uses the above .h file)

```
static Struct_C myNewStruct; // ISSUE: Call to implicitly-deleted default constructor??
```

Why do I get this error?
Anyway to make it work without touching the .h file?
If not..., and change in .h required, what is the minimal change I can do?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  What is `...`?

Comment: can't reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/7cde48oKr

Comment: I suppose the issue is with the parts hidden under `...`.

Comment: You have a const member variable somewhere?

Comment: Since the structures are clearly "dummy" there was no need to elide (`...`) them.  Are you certain that the issue can be reproduced with just what you have provided (with the elide omitted)?  What toolchain did you use, what version, what C++ standard conformance?  Because we are all struggling to reproduce the issue to seems.  Though clearly you have omitted C linkage.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica : Genius - reproduced it now; clearly the OP did not check that the code provided reproduced the problem.

Comment: I do believe the edited code reproduces the issue.

Comment: Somewhere in the elided code you perhaps have an uninitialised `const` variable.  It is not clear why you would have a `const` in a C structure - the semantics of `const` in C++ are significantly different from C.  You can initialise a `const` in a C__ struct but not in a C struct.  So if you fix it for C++, you will break it for C.  You could use conditional compilation but the semantic differences may still defeat your attempt.

Comment: @schantischul -- *My header file: (got it from external source)* -- If you don't see `#ifdef __cplusplus` inside that header file, that header file was meant for only `C` modules, with no knowledge of C++.  Obviously the author or vendor never intended that header to be used in a C++ module, else they would have discovered the error themselves and addressed it.

Answer (score 4):

C++ won't let you leave the value of a const variable "hanging" in default initialization. Even a static one, that will go through zero-initialization first. It isn't *assumed* you want that.

Fortunately, you can opt-in explicitly by providing an initializer:

```
static Struct_C myNewStruct{};
```

Same effect, different paths to get there for those of us who language-lawyer. Now it's value initialization, so you get the zeroes you explicitly asked for.

Comment: But with the initialiser it is no longer valid C.  That said, I cannot see how the unitialised const could be _useful_ in C in any case.

Comment: @Clifford - From the OP: *"My cpp file:"*

Comment: My error - I did not spot that your initialisation was of the instance rather than the member.